# Calculating Probability

Tags: probability

(a) Find the probability of having more girls than boys in a family of 8 children.
(b) Find also the probability that among 5 families, each with 8 children, more
than 2 of the families have more girls than boys.

Comment: As you are new to the site:  people here tend not to respond well to questions (like this one) that show no effort and which look like routine homework exercises.  What have you tried?  Edit the question to show your efforts and to indicate where you are getting stuck.

Comment: Your part (a) is pretty straight forward. Make sample spaces and see the resulting ans to be 4/9

Answer (score 0):

Your part (a) is simply comparing elements in sample space $\{S:(Daughter,Son)\} $ which is $S=\{ (0,8);(1,7);(2,6);(3,5);(4,4);(5,3);(6,2);(7,1);(8,0)\}$

which simply makes your probability: $\frac{4}{9}$